# Map a virtualhost to a directory in another server

Tags: apache, virtualhost, proxypass

guys! I created a subdomain, e.g. subdomain.server.com and I'd like to map it to a directory that is in another server in our network 192.168.1.100/dir

I tried using proxypass and proxyreverse as usual:

ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.100/dir
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.100/dir

But it did not work. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: You need a webserver on 192.168.1.100 serving up `/dir` in some way

Comment: Oh, my! How could I forget about this?! lol thank you! :)